# Installing memcache in Windows 7 (XAMPP)

Tags: php, windows, apache, memcached, xampp

I'm using Windows 7, 64 bits, and PHP 5.3.5.

memcache is showing as this in phpinfo:

```
Active persistent connections: 0
Version: 2.2.5
Revision: $Revision: 1.114 $
```

And I'm also getting a connection error `Notice: Memcache::get() [memcache.get]: Server localhost (tcp 11211) failed`

This is what I did:

1) I installed and ran the 64 bit memcached service: http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip.

2) I copied php_memcache.dll (https://thinkam.googlecode.com/files/php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip) into php/ext.

3) I added `extension = php_memcache.dll` in php.ini.

4) I restarted XAMPP.

What could I be missing?

*** Update ***

Memcache seems to be listening now on port 11211, but now from my application I get the following error:

> Notice: Memcache::get() [memcache.get]: Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211)
>   failed with: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
>   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>   (10060)

Comment: For different php versions you can get another php_memchace.dll from here 
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/

Comment: @Gigala Thanks a lot you save my day

Answer (score 3):

You must run `memcached server` in Windows  `Control Panel->Administration->Services`.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happens... Anything else that could be missing? If I type 'netstat' on cmd, I don't get the connection listed in there (maybe it should be there, since port 11211 is open?)

Comment: @luqita `memcached` is running as service? try to connect by `netstat` to 127.0.0.1:11212

Comment: Yes, memcached is running as a service now... I am now seeing this on netstat: TCP [::1]:11211 My-PC:58710   SYN_RECEIVED... Is that correct? Or should it be 'ESTABLISHED'?

Comment: correct ... try to add in properties of `memcached.exe` with `Compatibility with Windows XP`. Does U install it as `Admin`?

Comment: Yes, as admin.. It's not XP, it's Windows 7.

Comment: I understand. But you can run program in compability with previous Win-versions.

Comment: Yes... But how would that help?

Comment: I updated my question now, since it seems to be working... Running it as a service seemed to do the trick, although I get a new error now. But thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Run `path/memcache.exe -d start` and make sure memcache is started

Answer (score 0):

As @Gigala say in comments you can get another php_memchace.dll for different php versions from here http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8

Download the extension for your php version following this example:

**php_memcache-3.0.8-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip** as **"5.3"** must be your php version

This works for me